# The corresponding variable (name) does not print out correctly (numpy)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

The data are stored in three columns in csv file. 
I am trying to print the highest val with it corresponding name. For some reasons, even though it prints the correct highest value, it does not print the correct name which has the highest value. I use the following codes. Where does it go wrong?

```
import numpy as np
names    val
Jason    100
Jacob    250
Josh     90
John     80

name = data['Names']  # the first column in csv
val = (100, 250, 90, 80)

print(name[np.max(val)], np.max(val))
```

It should print Jacob, 250 but mine prints the correct val with the wrong name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.max(val)` is the maximum value from that array.  But `name[idx]` requires a index, not a value.  Have you tried `argmax`?

```
In [474]: txt='''names    val
     ...: Jason    100
     ...: Jacob    250
     ...: Josh     90
     ...: John     80'''
     ...: 

In [476]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), names=True, dtype=None,encoding
     ...: =None)
In [477]: data
Out[477]: 
array([('Jason', 100), ('Jacob', 250), ('Josh',  90), ('John',  80)],
      dtype=[('names', '<U5'), ('val', '<i8')])
In [478]: names = data['names']
In [479]: val = data['val']
In [480]: val
Out[480]: array([100, 250,  90,  80])
In [481]: np.max(val)
Out[481]: 250
In [483]: names[np.max(val)]
...
IndexError: index 250 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4
```

`names[250]` does not make sense, does it?

Using argmax instead:

```
In [484]: idx=np.argmax(val)
In [485]: idx
Out[485]: 1
In [486]: names[idx]
Out[486]: 'Jacob'
In [487]: data[idx]
Out[487]: ('Jacob', 250)
```

Or with a boolean mask

```
In [488]: val==np.max(val)
Out[488]: array([False,  True, False, False])
In [489]: data[_]
Out[489]: array([('Jacob', 250)], dtype=[('names', '<U5'), ('val', '<i8')])
```

`where` could also be used:

```
In [490]: np.where(val==np.max(val))
Out[490]: (array([1]),)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. very thorough explanation. I tried argmax and gave me the name with the second highest value. I tried np.where and gave me nothing. I think I need to rearrange my numpy array.

Comment: Are there duplicate `val` values?  or floats?  Other than things like that, order shouldn't matter.  But you can use `argsort` to sort the rows (records) of `data`.

Comment: Yes, there are duplicates in both names and val (int). I group the names and sum all the corresponding val first.